# How to loop through an array with keys and values in to send a request for Axios.get's params in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to implement a `delete function` where the user can select multiple files, then I will retrieve both the `fileID` and the `deletedBy` field. After mapping both `fileID` and `deletedBy` together, I will send them to this `deleteFile` function where in this case I need to send `3 axios get requests` accordingly and individually to delete the function, but I just can't make the loop work.

```
   const deleteFile = async (file) => {
        const responses = [];
        const url = 'https://api.com/delete_file_web';

        for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            responses.push(await axios.get(url, { params: {
                fileID: file.fileID,
                deletedBy: file.deletedBy
            }})
            )
        }

        Promise.all(responses)
        .then(response =>
            alert('File has been successfully deleted!')
        )
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Fix these: `fileID: file[i].fileID` and `deletedBy: file[i].deletedBy`

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, is there something wrong with my axios request instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `i` in loop.

```
const deleteFile = (file) => {
    const requests = [];
    const url = 'https://api.com/delete_file_web';

    for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        requests.push(axios.get(url, { params: {
            fileID: file[i].fileID,
            deletedBy: file[i].deletedBy
        }})
        )
    }

    axios.all(requests)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, is there something wrong with my axios request instead?

Comment: @Lance Make sure you are not using await keyword in front of axios.get.

Comment: @Danial Sorry, I've tried your method but the console returns undefined and I still can't get it to work...

Comment: @Danial Now it returns an empty array which is probably the initialized ```const requests = [];``` but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you for your effort and patience for helping me, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Danial it is still the same where the console just returns the ```[]```, I even added a .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }) but it doesn't catch the error as well

Comment: I test the code with a public API and did work. Are you sure about your api?

Comment: @Lance See this : https://jsfiddle.net/danialnoaein/w95e76nL/

Comment: @Danial I just realised something, when I passed the ```file``` array to this delete function, I actually need to do something like ```const deleteFile = (fileList) => {
const file = fileList.file``` (not sure what is this procedure called) and then I am only able to access it like ```fileID: file[i].fileID``` because the array has ```file``` as its name before I can access its content as shown in the screenshot I posted. Your code is actually working and I'm the one with the silly mistakes. Sorry for wasting your time and I thank you for your effort & patience again! Kudos to you!